# Scale of 15 years too big to see short events (of two days or so)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timeline

I have a scale that shows a timeline of 15 years. All the events are drawn as rect in that timeline and everything works fine. But when I have a short event like 2 days or so you do not see the event until you zoom in that particular timespan. Do you have any idea how I could make it seen already without zooming? Adding some days to the event to make it seen from the beginning would solve the problem only as long as I do not zoom to see the wrong timespan. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is that timeline? How is it constructed? Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Show a point or something which is clickable by the user and zooms in for him? I think this question is maybe better suite for [UX Stack](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks you two for your willing support!!! Lucky enough I figured out a way to do it: using for the short events lines instead of rects will display them for every size...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use .append('line') instead of .append('rect') solves the problem.